# Sympy refuses to calculate values

Tags: python, numeric, sympy

I'm trying to implement a markdown-like language to do math with. The basic idea is to have a file where you can write down your math, then have a python-script do the calculations and spit out tex.

However, I'm facing the problem, that Sympy refuses to spit out values, it only gives me back the equation. Much weirder is the fact, that it DOES spit out values in an alternate test-script, that is essentially the same code.

This is the working code:

```
import sympy as sp
m = sp.symbols('m')
kg = sp.symbols('kg')
s = sp.symbols('s')
g = sp.sympify(9.80665*m/s**2)
mass = sp.sympify(0.2*kg)
acc = sp.sympify(g)
F = sp.sympify(mass*acc)
print F
```

Output:

```
1.96133*kg*m/s**2
```

This the not working code:

```
import re
import sympy as sp
print 'import sympy as sp'

#read units
mymunits = 'units.mymu'
with open(mymunits) as mymu:
    mymuinput = mymu.readlines()
    for lines in mymuinput:
        lines = re.sub('\s+','',lines).split()
        if lines != []:
            if lines[0][0] != '#':
                unit = lines[0].split('#')[0]
                globals()[unit] = sp.symbols(unit)
                print unit+' = sp.symbols(\''+unit+'\')'

#read constants
mymconstants = 'constants.mymc'
with open(mymconstants) as mymc:
    mymcinput = mymc.readlines()
    for lines in mymcinput:
        lines = re.sub('\s+','',lines).split()
        if lines != []:
            if lines[0][0] != '#':
                constant = lines[0].split('#')[0].split(':=')
                globals()[constant[0]] = sp.sympify(constant[1])
                print constant[0]+' = sp.sympify('+constant[1]+')'

#read file
mymfile = 'test.mym'
with open(mymfile) as mym:
    myminput = mym.readlines()
    #create equations by removing spaces and splitting lines
    for line in myminput:
        line = line.replace(' ','').strip().split(';')
        for eqstr in line:
            if eqstr != '':
                eq = re.split(':=',eqstr)
                globals()[eq[0]] = sp.sympify(eq[1])
                print eq[0]+' = sp.sympify('+eq[1]+')'

print 'print F'
print F
```

It outputs this:

```
acc*mass
```

It SHOULD output a value, just like the test-script.
The same script also outputs the code that is used in the test-script. The only difference is, that in the not-working script, I try to generate the code from an input-file, which looks like that:

```
mass := 0.2*kg ; acc := g

F := mass*acc
```

as well as files for units:

```
#SI

m       #length
kg      #mass
s       #time
```

and constants:

```
#constants

g:=9.80665*m/s**2       #standard gravity
```

The whole code is also to be found on [github](https://github.com/turbinenreiter/MyMath).
What I don't get is why the one version works, while the other doesn't. Any ideas are welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: Near the bottom of your script, the second half of the equation, `eq[1]`, is still a string. It looks like `sympify` expects an actual expression (in this case, two variables and a multiplication).

Comment: from the docs:
_sympy.core.sympify.sympify(a, locals=None, convert_xor=True, strict=False, rational=False, evaluate=None)[source]
Converts an arbitrary expression to a type that can be used inside SymPy.
...
It currently accepts as arguments:
...
**strings** (like “0.09” or “2e-19”)
..._
edit:
however - you are rigth!

Comment: Ok, I changed:
sp.sympify(eq[1])
to:
sp.sympify(eval(eq[1]))
now it works. thanks for the tip, Evert!

Comment: `sympify` should work just fine with strings. I think you need to pass in your globals or locals dictionary so that it knows what you have things set to.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Everts comment, I cam up with this solution:

change:

```
sp.sympify(eq[1])
```

to:

```
sp.sympify(eval(eq[1]))
```

Comment: Since you're using `eval` here, and you allow (arbitrary) input through a user-file, you may want to be cautious. Perhaps `ast.literal_eval` can help you?